# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, netbeans

I have met the error when I am implementing a method in Netbeans.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have provided an instance of
an incorrect PK class for this find operation.
  Class expected : class java.lang.Integer,
  Class received : class java.lang.String.
```

Below are the entities that are used in the method:

public class Staff implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)

@Column(name = "STAFF_ID")
private Integer staffId;
@Size(max = 30)
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "ROLES")
private String roles;

@Size(max = 60)
@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "VERIFYSTATUS")
private String verifystatus;
@Size(max=10)
@Column(name = "VERIFYCODE")
private String verifycode;

public Staff() {
}

public Staff(Integer staffId) {
    this.staffId = staffId;
}

public Integer getStaffId() {
    return staffId;
}

public void setStaffId(Integer staffId) {
    this.staffId = staffId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(String roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getVerifyStatus() {
    return verifystatus;
}

public void setVerifyStatus(String verifystatus){
    this.verifystatus= verifystatus;
}

public String getVerifyCode() {
    return verifycode;
}
   public void setVerifyCode(String verifycode){
       this.verifycode= verifycode;
   }

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (staffId != null ? staffId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Staff)) {
        return false;
    }
    Staff other = (Staff) object;
    if ((this.staffId == null && other.staffId != null) || (this.staffId != null && !this.staffId.equals(other.staffId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entity.Staff[ staffId=" + staffId + " ]";
}
```

}

The method in my controller:

```
public String verify(){
String result = "failed";
String authcode = staffBean.getVerifyCodeByName(getLoginUserName()); 
//get verifycodefrom database by name
Staff temp = staffBean.find(authcode);

if ( code.equals(authcode)){
    result ="success";
    temp.setVerifyCode("");
    temp.setVerifyStatus("Verified");
    staffBean.edit(temp);
}
return result;
```

My facade:

```
@Override
 public String getVerifyCodeByName(String name) {
 Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Staff.getVerifyCodeByName");
 q.setParameter("name", name);
 return ((String) q.getSingleResult()).toString();
```

My facadelocal:

```
public String getVerifyCodeByName(String name);
```

i am unsure which variable has the error in it. :(

Comment: Did you also annotate the field `verifyCode` as `@Id`? My guess is that your entity class doesn't declare an `@Id` field or declares a different (non-String) `@Id` field.

Comment: The annotation of @Id was at the beginning of my code

Comment: Why is this related to Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess the Problem comes on the line:

```
Staff temp = staffBean.find(authcode);
```

You try to search for a Staff instance, based on a string. But the search you would like to do should be based on an Integer, as this is your @Id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What is the primary key of your Staff object? You don't show us the whole class. The error message is saying that you are expected to pass an Integer and you are passing a String.

Comment: the primary key is my staffId. edited, sorry about that.

in my method of verify, both parameters used are String. I changed my facade code by referencing a similar facade code which used Integer instead of String. so i guess maybe my error's in the facade.

Comment: So what variable should I put instead of @Id?